# Adding rule to raster calculator?

Tags: raster-calculator

IF there are one or two urban cells in the Moore neighbourhood AND there is a road running through this cell.

How do I add this rule in my raster calculater?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot :IF there are one or two urban cells in the Moore neighbourhood And there is a road running through this cell THEN the cell is developed

Comment: you could use a tool like Zonal Statistics - assuming you're using ArcGIS... are you using ArcGIS? - then do a selection on your output to determine which cells have more than 1 road running through, then select the neighborhoods that intersect those cells as being 'developed'... ?

Answer (score 1):

The general workflow would be:

1. Create a raster with urban area cell values = 1
2. Run [Focal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Focal_Statistics/009z000000qs000000/), using the default neighborhood (3x3) and statistics type = SUM ("urbansum"). Resulting values of 1 and 2 are of interest to you.
3. Convert road lines to raster ("roadraster")
4. In raster calculator, use a statement like:

   Con((urbansum == 1 or urbansum == 2) & roadraster, 1)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have my "focal_statistic" raster for urban Development, and my roadraster "vej_raster". In raster calculator i wrote the statement:
con(("focal_statistic"==1 or "Focal_statistic"==2) & "vej_raster",1) but got error 000539. Anyone who can help with that? And how do I write "to" in the calculator?

Comment: Raster Calculator is case sensitive, so you need 'Con' and 'focal_statistic'.

Comment: Okay. I have to ad the rule to another rule. First I got
Con("Focal_statistic">=3,1,0). That Works ok. Then I shall add rule nr.2 and I have:
Con("Focal_statistic">=3,1,0) AND Con(("Focal_statistic"==1 OR "Focal_statistic"==2) & "vej_raster",1) Then I get "invalid error" in raster calculator?